# Materialize CSS: Navbar is collapsing because of side nav - how to prevent?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am building a website with a nav bar and a side nav. The side nav should collapse, the nav bar (no a small screen) should not.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {'draggable':true});
```

Because of the code above, both the navbar and the side nav will collapse. How do I prevent the nav bar from collapsing?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to remove the `hide-on-med-and-down` class from the nav bar entries.